# Where does the shopware/development Docker Image Come From?

Tags: php, docker, shopware

Shopware's development enviornment setup includes [spinning up the `shopware/development` image](https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/trunk/docker-compose.yml#L8).  Unfortunately, this image's [Docker Hub Overview page](https://hub.docker.com/r/shopware/development) is blank.

If I navigate down [into the tags](https://hub.docker.com/layers/shopware/development/7.4-composer-2/images/sha256-c28bc434de61d2f3a57e323995b747d765c66337329b07104231f27d5fc8adea?context=explore) I can see the layers that make up this image, but they don't seem [to correspond to this `Dockerfile` in the repository](https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/trunk/dev-ops/docker/containers/app/Dockerfile).

Where does this `shopware/development` image come from?  What's its base image?

Asking because I'm having trouble getting this all to work on my M1 Mac and I'd like to track each Docker image to its source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking around in shopware slack  reveals that this is a https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/trunk/dev-ops/docker/containers/app/Dockerfile

https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/trunk/.gitlab-ci.yml#L58-L69 thats the code that builds that

This is what they promote for their docker instances https://dockware.io/ > https://github.com/dockware/dockware

Comment: Hmmm -- that seems right.  I'm not sure if I misread the layers from https://hub.docker.com/layers/shopware/development/7.4-composer-2/images/sha256-c28bc434de61d2f3a57e323995b747d765c66337329b07104231f27d5fc8adea?context=explore but it looks like they published a new image 11 hours ago that expired the one I was looking at -- but the latest image do seem to derive from the container in the GitHub repo.  +1 accepted.